# C# program error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

This is my code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int processId;
        Console.WriteLine(PlatformInvokeTest.LaunchApp(@"1f0f1577-bc5a-4c10-9a06-f939dc76a130_9tzsbvskx44gy!App", out processId));
        Console.WriteLine(processId);    
    }
}

public class PlatformInvokeTest
{
    [DllImport("MAF32.dll")]
    public static extern int LaunchApp(
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string processIdentifier,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int processId);
}
```

Even though I have included "using System;", I am still getting the following error:

`The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context.`

Could someone please help me figure this issue?

Comment: I don't see "using System;" in your code.

Comment: What's with all the down-votes, we were all beginners once.  The question is not vague at all, it's precise and has been answered.

Answer (score 10):

You wrote
`using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`
not `using System;` which is a different namespace (root namespace).

Answer (score 4):

I can only see one using statement:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

If you add the following using statement after the existing one, you should fine the Console reference resolves itself:

```
using System;
```

If you take a look at the [Documentation for the Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43zwz7ys%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class you can see it uses the [System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxcx7skw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) namespace.

Comment: I tried using "using System;" too, it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You have `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`, but to use the `Console` class, you need to add `using System;` to the beginning of your code.